# VueJS and ElectronJS | VueJS stops rendering completely when I import ipcRenderer in a component

Tags: vue.js, electron

So I am coding a VueJS and ElectronJS template which can be found here: https://github.com/dev-aethex/electronjstemplate

My code works something like this,
Inside of my Vue component I access a global pre constructed class called `MainProcessInterface` and when it's constructed it first checks if vue is compiled for running in a development server.  If it's in a dev server it will connect to the dev socket which electrons main process will host if electron is in dev mode and not compiled.  This method seems to be working great, I had to use a socket because vue dev server is being loaded into electron via `loadURL` and so vue has no clue what `ipcRenderer` is.  Inside the main process interface, if vue is compiled it will instead use the `ipcRenderer.send()` method.  This is were the problem was born.

As soon as Vue runs thought the TS code, it sees `ipcRenderer.send` and freaks out while printing an error to the electron window console saying fs.existsSync does not exist or is defined.

I can't find a way around this.  I though maybe i'll split `MainProcessInterface` into 2 peices, one for `ipc` and the other for `websockets`.  Although it isn't a very good way, so before implementing it, I would like to know if there is a better more proper way of doing such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue with React. Are you importing the `ipcRenderer` object somewhere in your build process? You might want to make sure it references the correct variable. I tried to drop this in as a comment but it wouldn't fit:

```
//index.html (index.ejs) for me... This is in the main HTML entry point

      var IPC = null;
      try {
        IPC = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
        console.log('IPC IS: ' + IPC)
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('CRICITCAL ERROR: IPC NOT ENABLED')
        console.log(err)
        IPC = null;
      }
```

Then I initialize off that context in React with a startup here:

```
     setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log('----------------HACK FIRED POST REHYDRATE')
        window.REDUX_STORE.dispatch( 
          (dispatch, getState) => {
            const _state = getState()
            if(window.IPC) {
              if(_state.osc && _state.osc.on) {
                dispatch( reconnectToEos() )
              } else {
                dispatch( updateStatus('[OSC Startup: DISCONNECTED]', ))  
              }
              console.log('\t------------ELECTRON')
            } else {
              //Shut off OSC
              dispatch( updateOscKey('on', false) )
              dispatch( updateStatus('[WebApp, OSC disabled]', ))
              console.log('\t------------WEB')
            }
          } 
        )
      }, 1000)
```

Basically I'm using a global variable (window.IPC) to initialize my app so I don't import a bad variable in my build process. I have a fair number of Electron APIs where this alleviates the issues with building via Webpack.

I hope this helps!